# Periodic Call on Dlialogflow fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I wonder if there is any way to make periodic calls to the user, for example:
In a case where the customer buys a pizza, and periodically the bot warns if the pizza is already ready or if it has already left for delivery.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [push notification](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications)s. Through the Google Home surface, there isn't a way to proactively reach out to the user.